# MySql - Updating Summary Table Periodically - Handle Updates/Deletes

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, materialized-views

We have the following tables:

| Table | Columns |
| --- | --- |
| compensation | account_id, amount, created |
| compensation__by_month | account_id, sum_amount, month |
| compensation__by_day | account_id, sum_amount, day |

`compensation__by_month` & `compensation__by_day` are summary tables, that aggregate the data from the compensation table periodically.

Every hour... we recalculate the totals for the last month, and replace the values in both tables with the new values.

My question is: how we do handle updates/deletes from older data on the summary table "periodically"? Is this not feasible?

The only way we can think of is not periodically, but with UPDATE/DELETE triggers on the `compensation` table.

We were just curious if there was a pure periodic approach we can do that takes into account older data that has changed.

---

We are big fans of Rick James' work over at http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

And used this post as a reference for these Summary Tables, however we could find no information on periodic updates to updated/deleted data.

Comment: Odd question you say you are recalculating  last month(month to date?) every hour - do you not have deletes/updates in current month and if you do how is that logically different from previous months?

Comment: Yes, so the current month gets fully recalculated and fully replaced into the summary tables periodically. So all updates/deletes will be taken into account since we are doing a full replace of the current months data every hour.

Older data however is not being fully replaced, rebuilding the entire summary table  using older data would take way too long.

Comment: Hmm - compensation_by_month and compensation_by day don't know what yyyymm they belong to. If you think that recalculating previous periods would take to long - presumably you have optimised what you have (if not publish full table definitions and explain plans) then triggers are the only option I can think of.